# NodeJS i18n for Javascript / JQuery files

Tags: javascript, node.js, internationalization, client-side

I'm using [i18n-node](https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node) in my NodeJS application but I can't use my .json files used for the translation inside my javascript files.

Is there something to use i18n-node client side for my javascript files ?

Comment: Also you might use your translations by using JS templates in client-side. https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node#attaching-helpers-for-template-engines

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) to use node modules in client-side javascript

Comment: Thanks for your answer I'll try that and accept your answer if it's ok